# StreamWriter keeps writing to the same file after instantiating it again for another file

Tags: c#, .net, logging, streamwriter

I'm trying to implement a simple file-logger object, with the possibility to truncate the file when its size reaches a threshold.

I am using a `StreamWriter`, which gets written to at each call of the method `Log()`. In order to decide when to truncate, I am checking the `StreamWriter.BaseStream.Length` property before each write and, if it is bigger than the threshold, I close the `StreamWriter`, create a new file and open the `StreamWriter` on that file.
For example, if I set the threshold to 10Mb files, it will create a new file each 10Mb of written data.

Under normal load (let's say 3-4 seconds between calls to `Log()`), everything works as it should. However, the product which is going to use this logger will work with lots of data and required logging every 1 second, even less.

The problem is that the logger seems to completely ignore the creation of the new file(and opening the new stream), failing to truncate it and keeps writing to the existing stream.

I also tried to manually compute the stream's length, hoping it would be a problem with the stream, but it does not work.

I have found out that going step by step with the debugger makes it work correctly, but it does not solve my problem. Logging each second seems to make the program skip the `UpdateFile()` method entirely.

```
public class Logger
{
    private static Logger _logger;
    private const string LogsDirectory = "Logs";

    private StreamWriter _streamWriter;
    private string _path;
    private readonly bool _truncate;
    private readonly int _maxSizeMb;
    private long _currentSize;

    //===========================================================//
    public static void Set(string filename, bool truncate = false, int maxSizeMb = 10)
    {
        if (_logger == null)
        {
            if (filename.Contains('_'))
            {
                throw new Exception("Filename cannot contain the _ character!");
            }

            if (filename.Contains('.'))
            {
                throw new Exception("The filename must not include the extension");
            }
            _logger = new Logger(filename, truncate, maxSizeMb);
        }
    }

    //===========================================================//
    public static void Log(string message, LogType logType = LogType.Info)
    {
        _logger?.InternalLog(message, logType);
    }

    //===========================================================//
    public static void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        _logger?.InternalLogException(ex);
    }

    //===========================================================//
    private Logger(string filename, bool truncate = false, int maxSizeMb = 10)
    {
        _path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, LogsDirectory, $"{filename}_{DateTimeToPrefix(DateTime.Now)}.log");
        if (CheckForExistingLogs())
        {
            _path = GetLatestLogFilename();
        }
        _truncate = truncate;
        _maxSizeMb = maxSizeMb;
        _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(File.Open(_path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite));
        _currentSize = _streamWriter.BaseStream.Length;
    }

    //===========================================================//
    private bool CheckForExistingLogs()
    {
        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(_path);
        var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_path);
        if (filename.Contains('_'))
        {
            filename = filename.Split('_').First();
        }
        return new DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles().Any(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(filename.ToLower()));
    }

    //===========================================================//
    private string GetLatestLogFilename()
    {
        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(_path);
        var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_path);
        if (filename.Contains('_'))
        {
            filename = filename.Split('_').First();
        }
        var files = new DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles().Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(filename.ToLower()));
        files = files.OrderBy(x => PrefixToDateTime(x.Name.Split('_').Last()));
        return files.Last().FullName;
    }

    //===========================================================//
    private void UpdateFile()
    {
        _streamWriter.Flush();
        _streamWriter.Close();
        _streamWriter.Dispose();
        _streamWriter = StreamWriter.Null;
        _path = GenerateNewFilename();
        _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(File.Open(_path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite));
        _currentSize = _streamWriter.BaseStream.Length;
    }

    //===========================================================//
    private string GenerateNewFilename()
    {
        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(_path);
        var oldFilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_path);
        if (oldFilename.Contains('_'))
        {
            oldFilename = oldFilename.Split('_').First();
        }

        var newFilename = $"{oldFilename}_{DateTimeToPrefix(DateTime.Now)}.log";
        return Path.Combine(directory, newFilename);
    }

    //===========================================================//
    private static string DateTimeToPrefix(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    }

    //===========================================================//
    private static DateTime PrefixToDateTime(string prefix)
    {
        var year = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", prefix.Take(4)));
        var month = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", prefix.Skip(4).Take(2)));
        var day = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", prefix.Skip(6).Take(2)));
        var hour = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", prefix.Skip(8).Take(2)));
        var minute = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", prefix.Skip(10).Take(2)));

        return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
    }

    //===========================================================//
    private int ConvertSizeToMb()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(_currentSize / 1024f / 1024f));
    }

    //===========================================================//
    public void InternalLog(string message, LogType logType = LogType.Info)
    {
        if (_truncate && ConvertSizeToMb() >= _maxSizeMb)
        {
            UpdateFile();
        }

        var sendMessage = string.Empty;
        switch (logType)
        {
            case LogType.Error:
            {
                sendMessage += "( E ) ";
                break;
            }
            case LogType.Warning:
            {
                sendMessage += "( W ) ";
                break;
            }
            case LogType.Info:
            {
                sendMessage += "( I ) ";
                break;
            }
        }
        sendMessage += $"{DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}: {message}";
        _streamWriter.WriteLine(sendMessage);
        _streamWriter.Flush();
        _currentSize += Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(sendMessage);
        Console.WriteLine(_currentSize);
    }

    //===========================================================//
    public void InternalLogException(Exception ex)
    {
        if (_truncate && ConvertSizeToMb() >= _maxSizeMb)
        {
            UpdateFile();
        }

        var sendMessage = $"( E ) {DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}: {ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{ex.StackTrace}";
        _streamWriter.WriteLine(sendMessage);
        _streamWriter.Flush();
        _currentSize += Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(sendMessage);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger.Set("Log", true, 10);
    while (true)
    {
        Logger.Log("anything");
    }
}
```

Have you ever encountered such a problem before? How can it be solved? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a race condition? Can multiple threads call `InternalLog` at the same time?

Comment: As I have mentioned, using the debugger and going step by step works just fine. The problem only happens on very fast logging.

Comment: OK, but surely something is causing the if condition to be skipped. This is not possible to know from here.

Comment: Only one thread at a time can call the method. The threads are synchronized.
Also, just by creating a new console application and calling the method inside a `while` creates the problem.

Comment: And which code sets that "_truncate" variable? Won't hurt to have complete reproducible example (one that anyone can copy, paste, run, and see the problem)

Comment: What does `GenerateNewFilename()` do? Can it generate the same filename again? Can you most a [mvce] which we can run? There's a lot of information missing from your question.

Comment: By the way, I would not try to implement a logger unless the environment requirements are really basic. There are a lot of solid and tested libraries out there.

Comment: I have uploaded the whole class code. Also, if I would be able to use a library for this, I would. Sadly, it must be custom made.

Comment: Please create a [mre], focus on minimal. There's way too much going on here, too many variables being modified. For all we know, you call it with `truncate` set to `false`. Your size calculation also is off, you ignore the newline character(s) length. C# doesn't randomly not call methods, so if your `UpdateFile()` method doesn't appear to be called, it isn't.

Comment: Still not very clear, since `_truncate` is only set in logger constructor, and logger is created by `Set` method not called anywhere in provided code (not to mention inside Set logger is created only if not exists already, so not clear how truncate can actually happen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much data your application writes to the log each minute. But if the amount is more than 10MB then the method DateTimeToPrefix will return the same name for a second call inside a minute interval. (Well at least for me this is what happens with the code included in the Main method).

I changed the ToString() to include also the seconds and this gives correct amount of data written in the expected files.

```
private static string DateTimeToPrefix(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. I kept looking for a much complicated reason but failed to realize this. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks "fine", so I'm guessing the issue is being caused by multiple threads accessing the `InternalLog` method at once. Your code is not thread safe as it does not use any locking mechanisms. The easiest and probably totally sufficient solution for your project is to add a locking object at class level:

```cs
private readonly object _lock = new object();
```

then wrap your whole `InternalLog` method in a `lock(_lock)` statement:

```cs
public void InternalLog(string message, LogType logType = LogType.Info)
{
    lock(_lock) 
    {
        // your existing code
    }
}
```

This is not a perfect solution and could cause a bottleneck especially as you are flushing the `StreamWriter` in every call to `InternalLog`. But for now it should be perfectly fine!

Comment: I have tried this approach, both on the `InternalLog()` method and the `UpdateFile()` method. It had the same result.